# What is the Linux equivalent for the Windows chkdsk command?

Tags: command-line, external-hdd, format, drive

I have an external drive used by Windows and Linux. It suddenly stopped working, suggesting that I should format it before use. I lost all of the data, name of the drive, and it doesn't even display the size.

Fortunately, Ubuntu sees everything. I looked for a Windows fix, but `chkdsk` can't access the drive.

I'm a new Linux user, is there an Ubuntu alternative? If so, how do I execute it?

Follow-up question:
In case I fail, how can I quickly create a live USB? My Ubuntu is installed on VirtualBox, and it doesn't accept any USB 3.0 ports. So in case I can't fix it, I'll need to back up my data with a live USB.

Answer (score 1):

The linux command to check disks is `fsck`. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting) for a rather complete reference list on what you need. My guess you will have to look for the ntfs section.

You also have to figure out which drive is which, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/157981/how-to-find-out-what-disk-drives-are-installed-in-a-ubuntu-server), basically `fsck -l`. You will feed the right drive name/number to the fsck utility.

If you have a working windows machine to install from, see [this help entry](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Good luck, let us know how you fare!

Comment: the fdisk -l shows

cannot open /dev/ram0 ...and all the other rams
cannot open /dev/loop0
cannot open /dev/sda
cannot open /dev/sdb
all of them PERMISSION denied. Could it be a virtualbox issue? 
i tried doing ntfsfix on sda and sdb anyway, but they are not accessible so its not even attempting to fix

Comment: ok, i tried it with sudo, we're getting somewhere, ill keep you posted

Comment: Cant access the drive on ubuntu anymore ;/ HELP

Comment: any command i put returns volume is corrupt, run chkdsk

Comment: indeed it is `sudo`

Comment: the last comment sounds desperate. Hope it is better now! Probably not. If the disk gets corrupted progressively (happened to me once) there is not much hope. There is a repair utility though ... googling...: believe I used this one at the time: [testdisk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/testdisk/)

Comment: test disk has access to the files. i want to copy them somehow. any ideas ?

Comment: Congrats! Try `cp -R <source> <dest>` after you have mounted your disk with `mount` (if u r lucky USB will automount under ubuntu). See also [here](http://lifehacker.com/5633909/who-needs-a-mouse-learn-to-use-the-command-line-for-almost-anything) for first steps in CLI.

Comment: No, no , ubuntu doesnt see the drive and i cant mount it manually. I'm saying that only testdisk sees the data

Comment: I'm copying the files using the testdisk tool on windows. i tried a couple of them and it worked.now im copying the whole bunch of 500GB, ill let you know.

One thing I noticed, after trying to fix the partition in ubuntu, TESTDISK doesnt  recognize the type as INTEL anymore. It suggests that it's NONE. Didn't cause any problems afterwards, but i'm just pointing out that the ntfsfix didn't fix. If anything it destroyed the 'partition table' (i think it's the right term, correct me if i'm wrong) . Anyway, it seems I have reached the solution. Probably if I knew more about ubuntu i could